# Colaboratory Google GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use Google Colaboratory with GPU. I mention I am working on Windows but this should have no effect. I selected the GPU accelerator with Python3 from Settings. When I hover over Connected it says that I am connected to 'Python 3 Google Compute Engine backend (GPU)', but when I try to check the gpu with

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.gpu_device_name()
```

I get nothing. Empty string. No error, but I cannot seem to be conencted to GPU. Did anyone have this problem? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Edit** menu, and select **Notebook settings**. Select **GPU** in the **hardware accelerator**, which by default is **None**.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I did that already and even though it seemed to connect successfully, trying to find a GPU resulted in error.